# перекодировка части страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, кодировка

Вообщем такое дело, есть сайт в кодировке windows-1251 и база в кодировке utf-8, сервер все успешно перекодирует в windows-1251, но в базе стал появляться арабский текст в именах и фамилиях, и на сайте имя и фамилия после перекодирования отображается как ????????? ?????????
у мня было 2 варианта решения этой проблемы

1. Выводить имена и фамилии ифреймом где ифрейм в другой кодировке(utf-8)
2. Сделать ajax запрос и поменять данные после загрузки страницы

Мне кажется есть более изящное решение может кто подскажет

ps: Полностью сменить кодировку как в базе так и на сайте нельзя

чуть позже было найдено вот такое решение , но я тоже не считаю его идеальным

```
<meta charset="windows-1251">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var tmp = decodeURIComponent($('div').html());
    console.log(tmp);
    $('.test').html(tmp);    
})
</script>
<?php
$textw = 'text текст windows';
$textw =  iconv('UTF-8',"windows-1251//TRANSLIT",$textw);
$text = urlencode ('DIMA IVANOV dima ivanov بِسْمِ اللّهِ الرَّحْمنِ الرَّحِيمِ'); 
echo $textw .'<div>'. $text.'</div><div class="test"></div>';
```

Comment: Сервер перекодирует всё через `iconv`?

Comment: да сервер перекодирует все через iconv

Comment: Полагаю база mysql, есть варианты `"SET NAMES 'cp1251'"`, для php `mb_internal_encoding('cp1251');`, а также указать кодировку в заголовке `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');` Может что-то из этого поможет. Не сталкивался ещё с такими проблемами, у меня база и сайт в 1251, скрипты в utf8 и никаких проблем

Comment: в cp1251 нет арабских символов в этом и заключается проблемма

Comment: Изящное решение это перейти полностью в UTF-8 и не городить костыли.

Comment: я писал выше что нет такой возможности

Comment: Почему нельзя изменить кодировку?

Comment: потому что придется рефакторить код написанный за 10 лет, а это очень очень много кода, написанного разными людьми. должна быть совместимость этого проекта с остальными так что не получится перекодировать только этот проект

Comment: А что сложного? Единственный момент - замена строковых функций на mb_ строковые функции. Больше никаких проблем быть не должно. Пользуйтесь поиском по коду. Будет нормальное правильное решение, чем городить iframe в utf внутри 1251

Comment: найдите мне человека кто согласится перекодировать несколько сотен тысяч файлов на разных серверах, и понесет ответственность за работоспособность всей системы после этого и да  все это за  бесплатно

Answer (score 1):

В 1251 давно уже никто не работает. Арабских символов в 1251 не существует. Переконвертируйте все файлы сайта в UTF-8 и не морочьте себе голову с iframe в другой кодировке.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше перекодировать весь сайт в UTF-8, но можно закодировать отсутствующие в windosw-1251 символы с помощью функции [`mb_encode_numericentity()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php)

```
echo mb_encode_numericentity($text, array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
```